# Data flips N/S orientation when projecting from GCS WGS84 to PCS Hartebeesthoek94/LO25

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, area, south-africa

I need to populate area field for a property layer in South Africa, but to do so I have to project the data from WGS84 to Hartebeesthoek94/LO25, a standard projection for South Africa which is avaliable in the QGIS CRS list. 
 When I do so, the data becomes completely flipped in North/South orientation. 
 Is this a known bug and can I edit the Y axis definition in the CRS to fix this?

Comment: This question may sound strange, but is it your Y-axis you encountered this issue?   (The point of my question is, the Hartebeesthoek94/LO25 EPSG 2051 seems to set axes: westing = Y, and  southing = X). I quickly checked QGIS's PROJ.4 for EPSG 2051 with [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/2051) website, and they look the same. Because this westing-southing system is not common (written as +axis=wsu), would suggest double check on it.

Comment: @Kazuhito, I'm not sure how to answer, but I suspect this is where the origin of the problem is. What I do know is I have never had a similar issue when doing this conversion in Arc, but I don't have access to a license at the moment, thus the necessity to do it in QGIS. I'm looking for existing data that may be in this coordinate system already to see how it loads in QGIS, but I have not found any yet.

Comment: Thanks for follow-up information on your Arc experience, Brendon. My experience with the Hartebeesthoek94 is limited to another [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215986/clipping-results-show-a-gmt-error#comment331259_215986) with which *Sibu* has worked on geographical coordinates. I have no direct knowledge about LO25 projection; my apologies if my comment above sounded authoritative. As your data has been working well with Arc, it vouches for itself. On the other hand correct CRS `+axis=wsu` does not necessarily mean QGIS can handle westing-southing as expected...

Comment: You were right Brendon, I came across a [bug report #8487](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/8487). So it seems southing is not used in the real world, while the flag `+axis=wsu` has flipped the map upside down. Choosing **ZANGI:HBKNO25** projection in QGIS may fix this issue. It gives `+axis=enu` instead of `wsu`.

Comment: @Kazuhito, thank you for the confirmation, at least it's not user error. For the moment I'm using UTM35s for area measurement. It should be accurate enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brendon, I had a chance to ask my friend to check his ArcGIS (10.1) how it handles Hartebeesthoek94/LO25; and this is my update (and hopefully close-out) summary.

[ArcGIS]

Hartebeesthoek94/LO25 is in northing and easting coordinates.

```
Geographic:
Name: GCS_Hartebeesthoek_1994
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_Hartebeesthoek_1994
Spheroid: WGS_1984
Semimajor Axis: 6378137.0
Semiminor Axis: 6356752.314245179
Inverse Flattening: 298.257223563

Projection: 
Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting: 0.0
False_Northing: 0.0
Central_meridian: 25.0
Scale_Factor: -1.0
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.0
Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)
```

Regulator also seems to have been suggesting USERs to modify grid if necessary, as seen in an example of [Durban City](http://www.durban.gov.za/City_Services/engineering%20unit/Surveying_Land_Information/Documents/SouthAfricanCoordinateSystems.pdf). So it is largely up to users to (or not to) set the grid to southing, using formula:

```
X value (UTM) = Y value (SA) x( –1)
Y value (UTM) = X value (SA) x( –1)
```

(NB. *sic "UTM" ...*)

[EPSG]

EPSG 2051 and all other "Hartebeesthoek94/LOxx" are set as `+axis=wsu`, and so far (it seems) there is no plan to introduce northing option.

[QGIS 2.x]

EPSG grids are honored, so it is basically southing if we set it to EPSG 2051; but if northing grid `+axis=enu` is required it is provided as **ZANGI:HBKNO25** .

And I do agree that **UTM35S** would give you enough accuracy, within a few meters (and it provides consistency with previous maps, too).